# VBA Match Function "Method 'Match' of Object 'WorksheetFunction' Failed"

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to use the Match VBA function in a programming project in Excel to get the first row number with a "1" in it. The code I'm using is:

```
Dim BorradorVar As Integer
BorradorVar = WorksheetFunction.Match(1, Sheets("Usuarios").Range("A1,A100"), 0)
```

Can someone explain what I'm doing wrong? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should refer to `Range` as

```
Range("A1:A100")
```

instead of

```
Range("A1,A100")
```

Using comma you refer to `A1` and `A100` only.

Also, if you are not sure if there is a match or not, you can use `Application.Match` and store the result in a `Variant` variable instead. The difference is that `Application.Match` returns an error when it fails, and then you can check if it has failed or not.

Example (check [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff835873.aspx) for full code):

```
Dim var As Variant

var = Application.Match(Cells(iRow, 1).Value, Worksheets(iSheet).Columns(1), 0)

If Not IsError(var) Then
    Debug.Print "There is actually a match"
Else
    Debug.Print "No match found"
End IF
```

A word of warning: If you match after row `32,767` [your code will not run](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10558540/vba-macro-crashes-after-32000-rows), because it exceeds the range of `Integer`. I suggest using `Long` instead of `Integer`. [Using Long is better practice in `VBA`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa164506(v=office.10).aspx) anyway.

Finally, note that if someone changes the name of the worksheet, this code will not run. [It is safer to refer to the worksheet by using its sheet ID instead of its name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27169070/identifying-a-worksheet-other-than-by-its-name/27169154#27169154) (Disclaimer: I have written the accepted response to that question).